# what is the most efficient way to select any row as the header row in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame that has some 561 columns and around 7300 rows. Now the problem is that I haven't been able to delete the first header row that has V1...V561 as the variable names and instead switch it over to the row below that includes the actual variable names. I tried a lot of techniques since I've already gone through a number of stack posts here, but none of them seems to be working in my situation. I even tried `colnames(df) <- lapply(df[1,], as.character` but it doesn't really seem to work. In addition, I could use some help with another alternative, the names() function but I don't know how to use it for my purpose.

lets just say I have two data frames, one containing a single column of 561 cells that are to be transformed as variable names for the second data frame that has V1...V561 as variable names. See what I mean? I need to replace that column of 561 cells from data frame 1, transforming them at the top of the second data frame, so I could have the actual variable names. Someone told me to use the names() function but I'm not that clear on the exact syntax since I haven't really used this function much.

**Edit**

Heres a much better way to describe of what needs to be done.

So this is df1 that contains the single column that I need to put on the very first row of df2.

```
df1

x
These
are
the
variables

df2

x    y    z   x1
0    1    2   3
1    2    3   4
2    3    4   5
```

That has to be transformed into

```
df2
These    are    the   variables
0        1      2     3
1        2      3     4
2        3      4     5
```

Comment: did you use `read.table(..., header=T)`?

Comment: Actually yes, I did mention header = T, but that won't make sense here since I have a data frame that strangely doesn't have the real variable names. The variable names, as I told, is in another data frame with only the variables in one column only. And I need to put that whole column on top of the second data frame in the form of a row.

Comment: `names(df2) <- df1[,1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df1` is the data you are trying to rename, `df2` has a row called `row` that contains the names you want, try

```
names(df1) <- sapply(df2[row,], as.character)
```

`as.character` because strings are likely factors.

#### Edit

Just noticed you said the names were in a column, so if the column with the names is `cols`

```
names(df1) <- as.character(df2$cols)
```

Comment: This is elegant, indeed

Comment: Thanks for the highlight nong! I'll try this and revert back if it works.

Comment: Seems I bumped into another obstacle. I tried the above method but now I get an error that says the `names attribute [561] should be the same as the vector [1]`. Now I did separately run the names() on df1 to figure out why this happened but all it gives me is the name of the column, perhaps thats why its length is only 1 which is not matching up with the table needed to rename since it has a row of 561 names?

Comment: Finally nailed em! Thanks for the guidance brother! I was doing the silly mistake of doing names(df2) instead of df1. And I instead modified the first command you told me, instead of `names(df1) <- sapply(df2[row,])`, I used `[,column]` since I had to take the column and replace it as a row. Whatsoever, a big thanks again!